# Does GHS Compiler support Importing functions from dll?

Tags: c++, c, greenhills

One supplier has shared a dll in which some functions (confidential) is present. Does the GHS Compiler allow importing these functions into C/C++ files using the import options (__declspec(dllimport))?

Comment: Why not ask Greenhills? Which version (i.e. which compiler specifically) are you talking about anyway?

Comment: Doesn't the DLL come with any kind of header file or import library?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the GHS compiler?  In every version of GHS Integrity I used the answer would be no.

Also GHS has told me that they don't support using binaries compiled with other compilers.